# convert utf8mb4 characters to utf8 in php

Tags: php, mysql, utf8mb4

is there a way to convert utf8mb4 characters to utf8 to store in a utf8 mysql database? and then when we get it from database, restore it to utf8mb4.

goal is storing phone smiley in a utf8 database without having to change database encoding.

for example replace first byte of those characters to a special byte and then in restoration change it back?

Answer (score 2):

ok what I did was using BLOB type for that column..