# utf8 vs utf8mb4-noone allows entry of every character

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

i am trying to store different types of languages in mysql and utf8 allows me to do so but when any images are there in that content utf8 breaks at that moment and only partial content is being inserted same is being solved with utf8mb4 character set but it does not allow hindi  and other regional character.

can anyone tell which character i should use.

i searched and found that blob will allow in this thread but when i am changing the content type to blob i am getting 1060 error.
           [convert utf8mb4 characters to utf8 in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273120/convert-utf8mb4-characters-to-utf8-in-php)

Any guide will be appreciable

```
   Punjab me 1Train k niche 100 Sardar aa gaye..

   99 Mar gaye...

   1 Bach gaya
```

in utf8 it will be inserted upto train and in utf8mb4 complete will be inserted but when i try to insert this

```
      एक छोटी लड़की ने अपनी दादी से पूछा, 'दादी मां, रोज रात को हमारे घर एक आदमी और एक औरत आते हैं और सुबह गायब हो जाते हैं। वे दोनों कौन हैं?' दादी मां : 'हे भगवान, तो तूने उन्हें देख लिया। बेटी, वे दोनों तेरे मम्मी-पापा हैं, जो कई साल से नोएडा में हमारे साथ रहते हैं और गुड़गांव में जॉब करते ह
```

utf8 will work but utf8mb4 will fail.
plz help